# Remove trailing decimal values to 1 place in sql server 2008 with money format

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have number in DB column and i want to format this with money,decimal data types.

my query is like below,

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(CAST(CAST(HouseholdCoverage AS DECIMAL(10,1))/ 12 AS DECIMAL(10,1))
AS money),1) AS HouseholdGoodsInsuredAmount FROM Table
```

HouseholdCoverage = 1175012

My query returns the value like below,

```
97,917.70
```

but i want result as

```
97,917.7 (only 1 number after decimal places).
```

If i cast the value as float i am getting error.

I know i can use parsename to separate the values after decimal place and add it again with few modifications. But that is not good i feel.

As well as i know this has to be done in C# application, but this query is already written in sql server 2008, i just want modify it according to requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out myself after doing some extensive research.. but dont know performance will be good or bad

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(CAST(CAST(HouseholdCoverage AS DECIMAL(10,1))/ 12 AS DECIMAL(10,1))AS money),1),
len(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(CAST(CAST(HouseholdCoverage AS DECIMAL(10,1))/ 12 AS DECIMAL(10,1))AS money),1))-1) 
AS HouseholdGoodsInsuredAmount FROM Table
```

Now the result is as i expected with 1 decimal places after decimal point,

> ```
> 97,917.7
> ```

Comment: Actually with `128` as the divisor (i.e. `DECIMAL(10,1))/ 128`), the result is `9,179.8`.  I think you meant the divisor to remain `12` (i.e. `DECIMAL(10,1))/ 12`), no?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep is simple. Divide your number by a decimal number and cast the answer as DECIMAL(10,1)

```
DECLARE @HouseholdCoverage BIGINT = 1175012

SELECT CAST(@HouseholdCoverage/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,1))
```

DECIMAL(10,1) will make sure that there will be only 1 number after precision(.)